# Cases or Select for catching elements in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have A list that contains  sublists like that:

```
    [{"Full ", 0.0003` "_r arcmin", "04 32 01.842" "_RAJ2000 \"h:m:s\"", 
  "+53 54 39.04" "_DEJ2000 \"d:m:s\"", 21148 "HIP ", "n_ " "P", 
  15 "Sn ", 3 "So ", 68.00768144` "RArad deg", 
  53.91084624` "DErad deg", -4.6` "Plx mas", 
  1.85` "e_ mas", -1.29` "pmRA mas/yr", -0.17` "pmDE mas/yr", 
  5.8249` "Hpmag mag", 0.119` "B-V mag", "HIP1" "HIP1 "} ];
```

And I need the Plx values as its HIP  , as:

```
{-4.6` ,21148};
```

A tried Cases, and Select but it did not work:

```
Select or Cases[REAL_ ~~ "Plx mas",REAL_~~"HIP "][List]:
```

The List:

```
{{"Full ", 0.0003 "_r arcmin", "04 32 01.842" "_RAJ2000 \"h:m:s\"", 
  "+53 54 39.04" "_DEJ2000 \"d:m:s\"", 21148 "HIP ", "n_ " "P", 
  15 "Sn ", 3 "So ", 68.0077 "RArad deg", 
  53.9108 "DErad deg", -4.6 "Plx mas", 
  1.85 "e_ mas", -1.29 "pmRA mas/yr", -0.17 "pmDE mas/yr", 
  5.8249 "Hpmag mag", 0.119 "B-V mag", "HIP1" "HIP1 "}, {"Full ", 
  0.0008 "_r arcmin", "22 39 15.679" "_RAJ2000 \"h:m:s\"", 
  "+39 03 00.97" "_DEJ2000 \"d:m:s\"", 111841 "HIP ", "" "n_ ", 
  5 "Sn ", 0, 339.815 "RArad deg", 39.0503 "DErad deg", 
  1.89 "Plx mas", 
  0.22 "e_ mas", -0.32 "pmRA mas/yr", -5.46 "pmDE mas/yr", 
  4.8135 "Hpmag mag", -0.207 "B-V mag", "HIP1" "HIP1 "}, {"Full ", 
  0.0006 "_r arcmin", "22 02 04.573" "_RAJ2000 \"h:m:s\"", 
  "+58 00 01.31" "_DEJ2000 \"d:m:s\"", 108772 "HIP ", "n_ " "P", 
  5 "Sn ", 0, 330.519 "RArad deg", 58.0004 "DErad deg", 
  1.07 "Plx mas", 
  0.18 "e_ mas", -2.72 "pmRA mas/yr", -2.74 "pmDE mas/yr", 
  5.546 "Hpmag mag", 0.017 "B-V mag", "HIP1" "HIP1 "}, {"Full ", 
  0.0483 "_r arcmin", "06 40 58.660" "_RAJ2000 \"h:m:s\"", 
  "+09 53 44.72" "_DEJ2000 \"d:m:s\"", 31978 "HIP ", "n_ " "W", 
  15 "Sn ", 3 "So ", 100.244 "RArad deg", 9.89576 "DErad deg", 
  3.55 "Plx mas", 
  0.5 "e_ mas", -2.61 "pmRA mas/yr", -1.61 "pmDE mas/yr", 
  4.5554 "Hpmag mag", -0.233 "B-V mag", "HIP1" "HIP1 "}, {"Full ", 
  0.0003 "_r arcmin", "18 15 12.906" "_RAJ2000 \"h:m:s\"", 
  "-20 43 41.77" "_DEJ2000 \"d:m:s\"", 89439 "HIP ", "" "n_ ", 
  7 "Sn ", 0, 273.804 "RArad deg", -20.7283 "DErad deg", 
  0.1 "Plx mas", 0.45 "e_ mas", 
  1.6 "pmRA mas/yr", -1.51 "pmDE mas/yr", 5.3438 "Hpmag mag", 
  0.007 "B-V mag", "HIP1" "HIP1 "}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using same data name as kguler

```
Cases[data, Times[x_, "Plx mas" | "HIP "] :> x, -1]
(*{21148, -4.6, 111841, 1.89, 108772, 1.07, 31978, 3.55, 89439, 0.1}*)

First /@ Select[data // Flatten, 
  Length@# >= 2 && (#[[2]] === "Plx mas" || #[[2]] === "HIP ") &]
 (*{21148, -4.6, 111841, 1.89, 108772, 1.07, 31978, 3.55, 89439, 0.1}*)
```

Answer (score 6):

With `data` as in kguler's answer:

```
data /. {___, b_ "HIP ", ___, a_ "Plx mas", ___} :> {a, b}
(* Out: {{-4.6, 21148}, {1.89, 111841}, {1.07, 108772}, {3.55, 31978}, {0.1, 89439}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Cases[data, (r_Real|r_Integer) s_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "*HIP*"|"*Plx*"] &) :> r, {0, Infinity}]
(* {21148, -4.6, 111841, 1.89, 108772, 1.07, 31978, 3.55, 89439, 0.1} *)
```

where

```
data = {{"Full ", 0.0003 "_r arcmin", 
   "04 32 01.842" "_RAJ2000 \"h:m:s\"", 
   "+53 54 39.04" "_DEJ2000 \"d:m:s\"", 21148 "HIP ", "n_ " "P", 
   15 "Sn ", 3 "So ", 68.0077 "RArad deg", 
   53.9108 "DErad deg", -4.6 "Plx mas", 
   1.85 "e_ mas", -1.29 "pmRA mas/yr", -0.17 "pmDE mas/yr", 
   5.8249 "Hpmag mag", 0.119 "B-V mag", "HIP1" "HIP1 "}, {"Full ", 
   0.0008 "_r arcmin", "22 39 15.679" "_RAJ2000 \"h:m:s\"", 
   "+39 03 00.97" "_DEJ2000 \"d:m:s\"", 111841 "HIP ", "" "n_ ", 
   5 "Sn ", 0, 339.815 "RArad deg", 39.0503 "DErad deg", 
   1.89 "Plx mas", 
   0.22 "e_ mas", -0.32 "pmRA mas/yr", -5.46 "pmDE mas/yr", 
   4.8135 "Hpmag mag", -0.207 "B-V mag", "HIP1" "HIP1 "}, {"Full ", 
   0.0006 "_r arcmin", "22 02 04.573" "_RAJ2000 \"h:m:s\"", 
   "+58 00 01.31" "_DEJ2000 \"d:m:s\"", 108772 "HIP ", "n_ " "P", 
   5 "Sn ", 0, 330.519 "RArad deg", 58.0004 "DErad deg", 
   1.07 "Plx mas", 
   0.18 "e_ mas", -2.72 "pmRA mas/yr", -2.74 "pmDE mas/yr", 
   5.546 "Hpmag mag", 0.017 "B-V mag", "HIP1" "HIP1 "}, {"Full ", 
   0.0483 "_r arcmin", "06 40 58.660" "_RAJ2000 \"h:m:s\"", 
   "+09 53 44.72" "_DEJ2000 \"d:m:s\"", 31978 "HIP ", "n_ " "W", 
   15 "Sn ", 3 "So ", 100.244 "RArad deg", 9.89576 "DErad deg", 
   3.55 "Plx mas", 
   0.5 "e_ mas", -2.61 "pmRA mas/yr", -1.61 "pmDE mas/yr", 
   4.5554 "Hpmag mag", -0.233 "B-V mag", "HIP1" "HIP1 "}, {"Full ", 
   0.0003 "_r arcmin", "18 15 12.906" "_RAJ2000 \"h:m:s\"", 
   "-20 43 41.77" "_DEJ2000 \"d:m:s\"", 89439 "HIP ", "" "n_ ", 
   7 "Sn ", 0, 273.804 "RArad deg", -20.7283 "DErad deg", 
   0.1 "Plx mas", 0.45 "e_ mas", 
   1.6 "pmRA mas/yr", -1.51 "pmDE mas/yr", 5.3438 "Hpmag mag", 
   0.007 "B-V mag", "HIP1" "HIP1 "}};
```

Comment: I didnt know about this command : (r_Real|r_Integer) s_String?; Could you explain more about its applications?

Comment: the list has elements that are reals or integers multiplied by strings therefore the pattern used for testing is `(r_Real|r_Integer) s_String`. In addition to that the OP wanted a constraint on the string so the string has to be tested to make sure it matches either Plx or HIP. If you get a pattern match then you want the value of the real or integer, `r`, returned.

Comment: Clean, and elegant way to get mixed elements, I did not realize that Number was multiplying string. Thanks.